# Some senses open, some we can shut

Tags: sources-mekorot, speech-talking, see-sight-vision-blind, hearing

I recently heard a question, why can we close our eyes and mouth without our hands, but not our nose* and ears?

I believe this sounds like the perfect question to ask the Torah. Does anyone have any sources related to the above question?

<sup>* truth is, we can shut our nose, from the inside</sup>

Comment: Maybe because Hashem created humans with the ability to withstand certain challenges / the yetzer hara and some senses need more help than others? There is the famous gemara in Arachin that Hashem created the mouth with two gates i.e. first the teeth and then the lips. In other words, Hashem created us imperfect but He also gave us innate defence mechanisms to fight the yetzer hara. There is also a gemara in Kesubos about how are fingers fit perfectly in our ears. Perhaps since eyes and mouth are more sudden in terms of our responses/reactions we can close them quickly.

Comment: ...Whereas with smell and hearing we can always move away

Comment: @Dov saw in Moreh Nevuchim 1:47 similar. He talks about taste and touch (I suppose smell and hearing can both be shut by our hands, but not touch and taste, so is a better question imo), fair enough, and shows they are never used in reference to Hashem because they imply direct contact. Perhaps that's where the lesson will come from e.g. the way we shut "touch" and "taste", is by removing _ourselves_, rather than just shutting those 2 senses. This goes with chassidic idea that food and relations are the ikar animal pleasures in life that need refinement