Moshe's Speech Impediment - a source for his humility?
Are there any sources that mention that Moshe's speech impediment was a contributor to his humility? E.g. people didn't show him a lot of honour and respect throughout his life due to it, as well as the fact that he noticed he wasn't good at effective communication and command, all of which he acclimatised to and never thought much of himself?
Moshe himself gives us this impression in Shemot 4:10 and 6:12, saying effectively "I can't take this task, because I have a speech impediment, and people will not take me seriously (e.g. Daat Zkenim), and I will not be able to articulate to them your commands in a way they will receive (following e.g. Ramban)".
However, that's just my subjective interpretation and I would like to know if anyone actually discusses this - did Moshe's speech impediment from a young age contribute to him achieving his trait of humility?. Perhaps we can learn about something about humility along the way, as well as some tips on how to improve our own humility.

Not humility, but perhaps related https://www.sefaria.org/Gevurot_Hashem.28.2

ענווה in the Torah is different from our definition of "humility".

Just a note—be careful not to conflate humility with meekness or insecurity. That wouldn’t be emotionally healthy, nor helpful for developing humility.

@QwertyCTRL. yes and I feel Y DJ also was concerned about this. I don't know how to edit the question to properly emphasise that I am limiting this to the Torah's definitions of humility only. Given that this is Mi Yodeya, that should already be implied but feel free to edit, either of you, to make it clearer if you like

@אילפא do you think you could have a look at this question? What you shared seems like it's "in the right ball park", and you may be aware of an answer or otherwise useful material: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/135699/some-senses-open-some-we-can-shut
